# How to log file name and current line in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, logging, boost

Hello I am trying to create a logger using boost.log with the format of

[Timestamp][Severity] - (FileName:LineNumber) Message

I already have the formatter but it throws an argument error when trying to compile this code:

```
fileSink->set_formatter(
        boost::log::expressions::stream
            << "[" << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "]"
            << "[" << boost::log::expressions::attr<severity_level>("Severity") << "]"
            << " (" << boost::log::expressions::format_named_scope("Scopes", "%n") << ":"
            << " " << boost::log::expressions::smessage
    );
```

It works when I remove the format_named_scope line though. I am unsure how else to do this and this is the correct way according to the [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html) . I do have all header files included also.

Comment: Use macro \_\_FILE\_\_  and \_\_LINE\_\_ ? In fact, I don't quite understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @DanaYan so in boost there is supposed to be a way to log the current file name and and file number when it log a message. It isn’t working however with the way I have it set up.

Comment: Regarding the file and line numbers you might want to red this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/boost-log/discussion/710022/thread/47198ea1/?limit=25#3c46 . Regarding the compilation error, it would help if you provided a compilable code example, compiler error and info about the compiler and platform you use.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I got it working. I wasn’t using BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPES() macro in the functions I was using the BOOST_LOG_SEV() macro.